# gridsearchcv best coefficients do not match well with the perfect line

Tags: python, regression, machine-learning-model, gridsearchcv, estimators

I wrote a program to find the best combination of coefficients to describe a variable. However, the coefficients from the gridsearchcv do not match well with the expected line. This is a sample of my data:

[image]

```
pipe = make_pipeline(process, SelectKBest(f_regression), model)
gs=GridSearchCV(pipe,params,n_jobs=-1,cv=5, return_train_score = False);
gs.fit(x_train, y_train)
fin = gs.best_estimator_.steps[2][1]; 
coef = fin.coef_; 
intercept = fin.intercept_
```

and these are the coefficients given:

[image]

Then if I plot the line with the coefficients:

```
xplot = 16.15589 + 1.13934372*df_loc.ChargeAmount + 1.605411*df_loc.PatientPrice + 6.81365603*df_loc.LastCost
plt.scatter(xplot, df_locpre.MSRP, color = 'black');
plt.plot(df_locpre.MSRP, df_locpre.MSRP, color = 'blue')
```

I obtain the following figure:

[image]

I think that either the scale is wrong, or some coefficients might be negative. Could you help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, it seems that the coefficient are simply scaled by the scaler I use. I have to reverse the transformation.
I have not found a good way to do this automatically, so I followed this:
https://www.tutorialguruji.com/python/how-linear-regression-coefficients-are-stored-in-sklearn-pipelines/amp/

If you know anything that might spare me from hard computing the values, please let me know!

Comment: Assuming that you are using `StandardScaler` to scale your data, you can simply use the [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform) method to transform the data back.

Comment: @Oxbowerce does this still apply if the transformation is inside a pipeline inside a specified search method (gridcv here)? I could not make good use of it to find coefficients

Comment: The `GridSearchCV` class also has an `inverse_transform` method, so that might work. Otherwise you can access the different steps within the pipeline using simple the [`steps` attribute](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#accessing-steps), so you could use that to select the scaler and use the `inverse_transform` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would just lean on the pipeline: `predict` instead of manually using the coefficients.

```py
xplot = pipe.predict(df_locpre)
```

Comment: would I still be able to get the unscaled coefficients from predict? The issue is that I have to output these coefficients and not just the resulting prediction.